# Drupal 9 core multilingual: cannot translate main navigation menu - button translate missing on menu items

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

I'm trying to catch multilingual features of Drupal 9 and have wamp64 local development server and clean Drupal 9.2.8 install.

I've enabled 4 multilingual core modules:

- Configuration Translation,
- Content Translation,
- Interface Translation,
- and Language.

Two languages enabled: en and ru.

I'm trying to translate Main Navigation Menu, but menu items don't have a "translate" button along with "edit" and "delete" at right side of menu links. So, no chance to translate menu items to RU language.

[image: Missing button translate]

So, please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close from it. You enabled the right modules, now, just go to `/admin/config/regional/content-language` (or via admin menu: Configuration >> Regional and language >> Content language and translation) and check the box "Custom menu link".

In the set of fields that appear below, select which properties of your menu items you want to be translatable and then hit "Save configuration".

Go back to your menu. You now have the available "Translate" option.